`useSearchParams` requires `Suspense` boundary, despite not exporting module
this is my current usage of useSearchParams:
  let rawValue = useSearchParams().get("val");
  let val = 0.001;
  if (rawValue) {
    val = parseFloat(rawValue);
  }

This is my only usage of useSearchParams, and I'm not using any external libs that could use useSearchParams.  What should I do?  I doubt this is the intended usage of the warning.  Any ideas?

Please share you full component code
